# Troubleshooting divs that have resized on their own

Tags: html, css, dimensions

I am currently building a div grid layout web page. Obviously I have been editing each individual square to fill a role. However for some reason I have noticed that although I have specified most of the divs as being `200x200px` and a couple being `200x400px` for some reason some of them have resized by an extra `10px` so the squares are starting to overlap. I did not have this problem before yet I do now. Could somebody please troubleshoot this? As I can not see the problem.

The issue is with the 'steps' divs and the 'special offers' div where the background has also resized to half the size. [Here is a livelink to the page in question, please look at the source code. I shall remove this when the question is answered for future posterity of the post.](http://www.mildenhire.com/Website/copyiframe.html)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="trigger">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; color: white;" tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"><img src="STEP1.jpg" height="200" width="200"/><p style="margin: 10px 20px;">Fill out our order form choosing the service you require and your payment details. We will then take a deposit and book you into our diary.<p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; color: white;" tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"><img src="STEP3.jpg" height="200" width="200"/><p style="margin: 10px 20px;">We will produce the work you require using the project plan. All of our work is produced Within the time limit set and to the highest possible standard.<p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="trigger">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; color: white;" tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"><img src="STEP2.jpg" height="200" width="200"/><p style="margin: 10px 20px;">We will have a face to face meeting to discuss everything that you require and we will put together a project plan.<p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; color: white;" tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"><img src="STEP4.jpg" height="200" width="200"/><p style="margin: 10px 20px;">A design is not finished until you are entirely happy. When we believe the work is complete we will send you an artwork approval form for you to sign and return.<p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cant access your local **pc** here buddy!

Comment: @Eirenaios hahaha sorry guys!!! fixed now! thats how fried my brain is because of this!

Comment: I've removed the superfluous `</div>` from your code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply this css

```
.trigger {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I tried that before I posted on here, if you take a look at the livelink I have updated it to show what happens, it cuts off the right side of the boxes on the end and also distorts the bottom div which contains an iframe

Answer (score 0):

If you are using padding for **.trigger** add **box-sizing: box-border;** property to it.

For more detailed help, post your css and fix the live link since it brings to a local file you have on your own!